# PHP: How to add spaces around "-" with RegExp

Tags: regex

I'm need to add spaces around "-" in the text (between the tags, not inside)

For ex:

```
1. <b>some-text</b> ---> <b>some - text</b>
2. <a href="http://site-link">some-text</a> ---> <a href="hhtp://site-link">some - text</a>
```

So, don't touch href link, only the text...
My expression don't work correctly with attr "href" of links:

```
$file = preg_replace('/>(.*?)([^\s\d])-([^\s\d])(.*?)</i', '>$1$2 - $3$4<', $file);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this regex:

```
$file = preg_replace('/(\>[^\-\<]*)-([^\<]*\<)/i', '$1 - $2', $file);
```

Also see [this example](http://ideone.com/dsqJe).

Answer (score 1):

Regular expressions are the wrong tool for this job.  I would use [DOMDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) to traverse the DOM and look for text nodes containing `-` characters, and replace them as necessary.